# I successfully installed a new add-on (stablediffusion-main) and now I can't find it

Tags: add-on

I installed this by the book. And it's located exactly where it should be.
[image: the folder where my addon is installed is correct]

And I cannot for the life of me find the little guy.

Where the heck is it and how do I get to it?

Comment: You've installed the wrong directory. There should be a `__init__.py` file at the top level of the directory.

Comment: Installed it by what book? If you install it the correct way it should automatically install into the correct folders. See [this](https://youtu.be/Y-H2Rp24HOY?t=51) tutorial by PIXXO 3D on installing and using it.

Comment: I went by this:
https://youtu.be/tmyln5bwnO8

I used the Pixxo method and it "installed" (thankyouverymuch) but AI Render does not show up where I'm shown to find it.

I'd be charmed to show you, but I can't insert an image here.

Comment: @HenryBirdseyeJr. You can't insert an image here? You inserted an image in your question, so what is the problem? You can insert more images there... and if it showing some additional information or clarification to the question, it is better to be placed in the question than in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Blender add-on. It’s clear from the files that are in this directory that it was meant to be installed as a module to vanilla Python. While it may be installable to Blender Python, the add on “installer” in blender just naively unzips the file you give it, and dumps a folder of the contents in the scripts/addons folder, expecting to be able to import an `__init__.py` file with Blender addon registration code. To install it properly to Blender Python is beyond my knowledge. Look for, “how to install modules to Blender Python with a setup.py file”.